# How to get the weights of columnconfigure in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I want to get the weights of all the grid columns in a frame and apply the same weights to a different frame with the same number of columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `columnconfigure` while only passing a column index, it will return a dictionary with all of the configuration values for that column. You can loop over each column to get the weight and apply it to the other frame.

The following example assumes you have 6 columns. Frame `f1` has already been configured, and `f2` should be given all of the same weights as `f1`.

```
for column in range(6):
    weight = f1.grid_columnconfigure(column)['weight']
    f2.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=weight)
```